# Automatically inject version tag into HTML file after git pull

Tags: git

I would like to put a placeholder into e.g. the footer.html and have it automatically replaced by the **version tag** set by `git tag xy` right after a `git pull`.

... something like a **post pull procedure**. Is there any quick way you can do this with git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **git hooks** to achieve this. There is no `pull` hook, but `pull` actually does `fetch` and `merge`, so you can set up a `post-merge` hook to automatically generate your `footer.html` file.

Read the relevant chapters on the [*Pro Git*](http://progit.org/book/ch7-3.html) and [*Community*](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html) books for more information.

Comment: Or `post-receive` (i.e. post fetch).

Comment: AFAICS, `post-receive` runs on the *remote* end (i.e. the server) when you run `git push`. I may be wrong, but that's how I read its description.